# python fileinput matching using wildcard

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to python... i'm trying to replace a specific value from a line in a txt file.

my current code

```
for items in some_dict:
with fileinput.FileInput(file_name, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
    for line in file:
        line.replace(items + (".*\d") , items + "\t" + some_dict[items].val )
```

the txt file will consist of lines looking like below

#define foo      8

my dict will consist of a new value to update it, the key from dict will be exactly like foo.

my dict is a class btw.

any idea how i can put decimal matching in there?

Comment: Your example contains one line, it might be faster just to overwrite the file.

Comment: my file is actually quite huge. i've got the correct way of doing it already, with sub.